# Error connecting: <class 'thrift.transport.TTransport.TTransportException'> Could not connect to localhost:21000

Tags: hadoop, hive, impala

I am trying to install cloudera impala on my local machine (32 bit ubuntu) without cloudera manager(they don't support on 32 bit ubuntu, i also tried and failed).

I have tried following commands to download the impala from repository.

```
    $ sudo apt-get install impala-shell
    $ sudo apt-get install impala             # Binaries for daemons
    $ sudo apt-get install impala-server      # Service start/stop script
    $ sudo apt-get install impala-state-store # Service start/stop script
```

Upto here it worked fine. My impala/conf/hive-site.xml looks like this

```
<property>
<name>hive.metastore.local</name>
<value>false</value>
</property>

<property>
<name>hive.metastore.uris</name>
<value>thrift://localhost:9083</value>
</property>

<property>
<name>hive.metastore.client.socket.timeout</name>
<value>3600</value>
<description>MetaStore Client socket timeout in seconds</description>
</property>
```

My impala/conf/hdfs-site.xml looks like this.

```
<property>
    <name>dfs.client.read.shortcircuit</name>
    <value>true</value>
</property>

<property>
    <name>dfs.domain.socket.path</name>
    <value>/var/run/hadoop-hdfs/dn._PORT</value>
</property>

<property>
    <name>dfs.client.file-block-storage-locations.timeout</name>
    <value>3000</value>
</property>
```

Now, i was trying to connect to localhost on impala-shell. But, it give me this error

```
Error connecting: <class 'thrift.transport.TTransport.TTransportException'>, Could not connect to localhost:21000
```

FYI, i am using mysql for the metastore for my hive-hadoop cluster.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue when executing the command from the statestore Node. Try executing `impala-shell` from any daemon Node. Worked for me!

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing in specifying `localhost` itself but the question is if appropriate service is available on appropriate port. I'd recommend first to check if service is available.

Following command will show you if service is listening on port (and on what IP interface).
It could be interface different from `localhost`.

```
netstat -a -n | grep 21000
```

Please pay attention `localhost` usually means IP `127.0.0.1` but in default Ubuntu configuration it looks like different IP address (like `127.0.1.1`). Recommended solution is to correct `/etc/hosts` (there is many articles about this). Also please check [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/39682/changing-127-0-1-1-back-to-127-0-0-1-will-it-break-anything-in-unity).

Comment: i checked with your command. it returned nothing, which means service is not running. I also checked the log, it show:   impala-serer.log    /usr/bin/impalad: line 60: /usr/lib/impala/sbin/impalad: cannot execute binary file
/usr/bin/impalad: line 60: /usr/lib/impala/sbin/impalad: Success
impala-state-store.log:     /usr/bin/statestored: line 60: /usr/lib/impala/sbin/statestored: cannot execute binary file             
/usr/bin/statestored: line 60: /usr/lib/impala/sbin/statestored: Success

Comment: Check appropriate 'binary' files. They really could be not as binary and contain references to external variables which are not set. Also I'd recommend CDH installation guide for newest CDH - there should be chapter for impalla - it is pretty new product (1.0 release was just about month ago and not so long ago it was 0.7).

Comment: Do you have any idea whether cloduera support the impala with apache hadoop? Currently i using the apache hadoop and trying to use impala to query hdfs or hbase.

Comment: Just install current Cloudera Manager Standard solution (now they call free CM as 'standard', version is 4.6 as far as I remember). Appropriate products are from CDH 4.3 which means 1.0+ Impala.

Comment: But, the problem is i have already setup the batch layer using apache hadoop version which Amazon aws provide. Now to shift to cloudera version hadoop is not possible. Is there any alternative of impala for doing the ad-hoc query? Plus please answer that question whether cloudera support the integration of impala with apache hadoop or not?

Comment: Looks like you have no alternatives (http://www.ymc.ch/en/comparing-cloudera-impala) if you really need ad-hoc queries. But do you really need this additional layer over HBase client? My experience is I can solve my tasks only with API. BTW (he-he, just curious :-> ) does Zmazon AWS allows coprocessors?

Comment: Please check impala installation docs, I'm pretty sure you missed some requirement to target system.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure all Impala Daemons are running: Impala Daemon, Impala Catalog Server Daemon and Impala StateStore Daemon.

That solved the problem for me.

Comment: how do we check those Lucas?

Comment: probably too late, but you should see them in cloudera manager (I am on CDP CM 
 7.4.2) -- anyway, that did not fix the issue for me

Answer (score -1):

This is happening because you are using localhost in your configuration settings. Use fully qualified domain name instead of localhost and restart the shell.